# Itunes does not play podcast

Tags: itunes, podcasts

Yesterday I downloaded the 64 bit itunes for my PC in order to play a podcast. I am unable to hear any of the podcasts. After I click play nothing happens. No audio. nothing

[image: sreenshot]

Comment: From what source did you download iTunes? Did you try another podcasts?